# Jquery problems jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer

Im trying to use this code to update the time in the console

```
(function($){
$.fn.playerConnect = function(player){
    var transcriptElements = this;
    player.onTime(function(evt){
        var time =  'timeUpdate'; 
        console.log(time);
```

But this error keeps coming up:

```
There was an error calling back an event handler jwplayer.js (line 4)
```

timeUpdate

How can I fix this?